# Required permissions to get the planner data using MS graph sdk?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I want to read the planner data using MS graph sdk. For authentication I have to use application type in my Azure AD. I have the client secret, client id and tenant id. The planner also has the permission for the whole tenant. I have given API permission for Group.Create, Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, User.Read.All with admin consent granted.

I was calling the api like this,

```
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();

try
{
    var planner = await graphServiceClient.Planner.Plans[plannerId].GetAsync(r => r.Options.WithAppOnly());
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Plan Id: {planner.Id}, Title: {planner.Title}");
    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

I was expecting to get the users list and the planner data. I got the users but for planner I got an error,
`Error: You do not have the required permissions to access this item.`

Now what are the permissions I require to get the planner data? or do I have to give some permission from planner end?

Comment: You also need permissions like `Tasks.Read` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get planner data using MS Graph SDK, you need **`Tasks.Read`** permission in **Delegated** scenario whereas  **`Tasks.Read.All`** permission in **App-only** scenario.

Initially, I ran your code without granting required permission and got **same error** while getting planner data as below:

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to grant **`Tasks.Read.All`** permission of **Application** type as you are using *client credentials* flow:

[image]

When I ran the same code again now, I got the **response** successfully with planner data like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "appId";
var clientSecret = "secret";
var plannerId = "plannerId";

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();
foreach (var user in users.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
}
Console.WriteLine();

try
{
    var planner = await graphServiceClient.Planner.Plans[plannerId].GetAsync();

    Console.WriteLine($"Plan Id: {planner.Id}, Title: {planner.Title}");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Get plannerPlan - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannerplan-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)